# Opencart Category Custom Icon

Tags: php, opencart, categories

I need to show a custom graphic icon to display on opencart category pages at the side of each thumbnail.

Can I use one of Opencart's existing product attributes to get this to display in categories?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to display that icon for product thumbnail or for category image?

Comment: its for product thumbnail,

Comment: I have created a vQmod extension for this. Wait until today evening I'll post an URL where to buy it.

Comment: Here You go: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=11268

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid That's Your problem. I don't need You to like me... And I didn't downvoted Yours, though I deleted mine as I consider it is not the right answer. I take criticism well - and on the side of criticism I always try to improve the answer/question, etc. And I am not rude and arrogant to others as You are, so tell me about pathetic developers... Have a nice day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`I have created a vQmod extension for this. Wait until today evening I'll post an URL where to buy it. – shadyyx 3 hours ago`

How nice of you my friend.. to charge something .. NOT

Basically you need to be editing the `category.tpl` file found in `view/catalog/theme/default/template/product`

You can either assign a simple `<img src=$id/cat_icons />` or something of that nature..

Comment: Thanks BlackBenz, the image I have is already in each product wherever this is set in admin and this works fine. So I need an if statement of sorts to display on the category page if the various products have 'available in colours'. Do you know what files I need to change? Thanks!

Comment: @user2191937 You can use the forloop of the product.tpl and category.tpl and also look in the controller files. Just do an IF conditional statement and load the entries associated to that item